# xlsx: error of adding massive number of rows to the worksheet - "invalid row number"

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I am using xlsx::addDataFrame to write 450,000 rows of a data.frame to a sheet and get the "Invalid row number" error. Can anybody tell me how to fix it? Or is there anyway to bypass this difficulty? Any command is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

> addDataFrame(x,col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, startRow=5,
>   +              startColumn=1, sheet=sheet2)
>   Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "newInstance", .jfindClass(class),  : 
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (65536) outside allowable range (0..65535)

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear, there is a 4 byte limit to the row number range.  Perhaps you could shrink your data set?

Comment: I should be more specific for the software I am using. I am using the R xlsx (0.5.7) package on R 3.1.3. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Tim, Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I cannot shrink my dataset. Each row represents an value on the human genome. That's why it is big.

Comment: Have you tried `write.xlsx`? You'll have to start on row 1, column 1, but there might not be a byte limit.

Comment: Hi, jmartindill, I am trying it now. It have been 45 mins and xlsx::write.xlsx is still working on it. It seems to work.  Really appreciated.

Comment: Hi, jmartindill, the xlsx::write.xlsx function bumped me out the R workspace after few hours of working. So I guess there is still a byte limit, from java maybe? Now I am using openxlsx that does not depend on java and I will see how it goes.  Thank you, Tim and jmartindill, for your prompt responses. Very appreciated.